# Android tileMode="repeat" and scaling

Tags: android

I have a simple problem.

This is my XML

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="45px" <!-- for testing only -->
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/bed_bugs"
    android:layout_width="0dip"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:background="@drawable/button_tab"
    android:src="@drawable/some_title" />

</LinearLayout>
```

And this is my Drawable `button_tab`

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item>
        <bitmap
             android:tileMode="repeat"
             android:src="@drawable/tile_test"/>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

`tile_test` is a simple image [image: image of tile_test]

My question is, how can I scale the tiled image?

This is what I have - [image: current]

This is what I need - [image: requirement]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think its imposable in xml, i created what i need in code 
1) get bitmap
2) resize bitmap 
3) create drawable with tileMode ( from resized pic ofc ) 
4) set background to you image with created drawable

its simple but not in xml (

Answer (score 0):

I did it just making the source image 1/2 it's size, so the pattern becomes smaller 1:2 scale. I think this is the best way as you use just one pattern I suppose.
[Original](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K9wrY.png)
[Scaled 1:2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u9lKj.png)

But..., it needs also a way to scale it, as image resolution will be always bad...

The best way to use the method is through a "pixel-art" image, so it will not be shown blurred. I followed this way in the app I made: [Implementation in my app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TOak2.png)

Comment: (please if someones see this upvote me, StackOverflow not allows me to publish answers anymore...)